# Linux Top command giving output of both the cpu cores using command line

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have a system with 2 cores running linux. I will want to log the cpu usages of the individual cores at regular intervals of say 15mins.

I can use top and regex to get the info. But it gives me the overall info of the cpu. When I manually press "1", then both the cores usages are shown separately.

My question is how can I display both the cores cpu usage without manually pressing "1" after invoking top command.

Current research by me:
-I can use the -b option to run in batch mode and output to a file. But the next question is how I can input data to the top command in the batch mode. Is there a script that top command reads to run in a batch mode?

Comment: Does the information from man top help?

Comment: I can figure out that I need to press 1 to see both the cpu cores individually. But I will be running this top command from a program. So I am trying to find a parameter that I can configure which gives me the cpu cores usage separately.

Comment: I found the expected answer. 1. run the top;
2. press 1;
3. generate a config file with the current configuration;
4. run the top command in batch mode using -b with one iteration using "-n 1";
5. This will list the individual cpus info;
6. The draw back is that the config file has to be generated and should be part of the source code; I guess, I can live with this till I figure out, how it can be done without the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux `top` command obtains its information from `/proc/stat` which is (somewhat) dependent upon the kernel version.  Perhaps you could write a program which reads from that.  Here is a sample from a 2.6.32 system with 20 cores:

```
cpu  46832272 794980 8521784 1312627944 853989 247 34947 0 0
cpu0 6404288 173468 806918 60455445 377313 1 1799 0 0
cpu1 2980140 137898 937163 64278592 68373 0 118 0 0
cpu2 5099227 86676 841568 62395343 27685 0 64 0 0
cpu3 11255325 20062 767603 56427120 9388 0 85 0 0
cpu4 2618170 1002 501629 65394095 4369 0 62 0 0
cpu5 635453 867 154898 67725523 2981 212 58 0 0
cpu6 343657 32 66510 68113208 2769 0 64 0 0
cpu7 327935 688 38431 68158263 1703 0 55 0 0
cpu8 118687 78 27436 68382190 1992 0 33 0 0
cpu9 329990 49 42224 68138515 1643 0 49 0 0
cpu10 3462177 160918 814788 63701724 202763 3 5444 0 0
cpu11 3006524 112533 484490 64877526 37455 0 6840 0 0
cpu12 2696919 61285 695966 65004324 17277 0 133 0 0
cpu13 3453005 34509 957663 64035215 10938 0 101 0 0
cpu14 2068954 2039 679830 65764151 6418 0 50 0 0
cpu15 628390 159 367213 67531841 2593 0 41 0 0
cpu16 331139 77 76690 68120995 2971 0 51 0 0
cpu17 616895 2482 182239 67595814 70070 29 19797 0 0
cpu18 343472 51 38712 68148369 2481 0 46 0 0
cpu19 111916 96 39803 68379681 2797 0 47 0 0
intr 1991637171 173 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 1 56 1416833 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1644 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2285 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3211641 4799987 3235 31624105 11000098 0 ...
ctxt 3201588026
btime 1460672984
processes 2430161
procs_running 2
procs_blocked 0
softirq 1391193131 0 626556634 166050 33864038 3892307 0 11210298 67287467 2880340 645335997
```

According to the man page (`man 5 proc` then search for `/proc/stat`), the lines for cpu entries are:

- The amount of time, measured in units of USER_HZ (1/100ths of a second on most architectures, use sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to obtain the right value), that  the system spent in **user** mode, user mode with low priority (**nice**), **system mode**, and the **idle** task, respectively.  The last value should be USER_HZ times the second entry in the uptime pseudo-file.
- **iowait** - time waiting for I/O to complete; **irq** - time servicing interrupts; **softirq** - time servicing softirqs.
- **steal** - stolen time, which is the time spent in other operating systems when running in a virtualized environment
- **guest**, which is the time spent running a virtual CPU for guest operating systems under the control of the Linux kernel.
- **guest_nice** time spent running a niced guest (virtual CPU for get operating systems under the control of the Linux kernel).

I looked at a 4.4.6 kernel system too.  The cpu entries have the tenth item.

Comment: Thanks Wallyk. This seems to be pretty clean for my purpose instead of running top and reading the configuration from the batch file.